# Difficulty in displaying a report

Tags: c#, reportviewer, layer

I'm developing for the first time in layers (Data, Business, Presentation), before I was doing it directly, now I want to show a report, these are the codes:

```
//DATA
//================
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace CapaDatos
{
    public class DCategorias
    {
        public int IDCategoria { get; set; }
        public string Categoria { get; set; }
        public string Notas { get; set; }
    
    public DataTable Mostrar()
        {
            DataTable TablaDatos = new DataTable("Categorias");
            using (OleDbConnection OleDbConexion = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbConexion.ConnectionString = DConexion.ChronusBD;
                    OleDbConexion.Open();

                    OleDbCommand OleDbComando = new OleDbCommand
                    {
                        Connection = OleDbConexion,
                        CommandText = @"SELECT Categoria, Notas
                                    FROM Categorias
                                    ORDER BY Categoria",
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    };

                    OleDbDataAdapter OleDbAdaptadorDatos = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleDbComando);
                    OleDbAdaptadorDatos.Fill(TablaDatos);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error al intentar ejecutar la instrucción. " + ex.Message, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    OleDbConexion.Close();
                }
            }

            return TablaDatos;
        }

        public List<DCategorias> Reporte()
        {
            DataTable tablaDatos = Mostrar();

            List<DCategorias> categorias = new List<DCategorias>();

            foreach (DataRow row in tablaDatos.Rows)
            {
                DCategorias categoria = new DCategorias();
                categoria.Categoria = row["Categoria"].ToString();
                categoria.Notas = row["Notas"].ToString();

                categorias.Add(categoria);
            }

            return categorias;
        }
    }
```

```
//BUSINESS
//================
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using CapaDatos;

namespace CapaNegocio
{
    public class NCategorias
    {
        public string Categoria { get; set; }
        public string Notas { get; set; }

    public static DataTable Mostrar()
        {
            return new DCategorias().Mostrar();
        }

        public static List<NCategorias> ReporteCategorias()
        {
            List<DCategorias> categoriasDatos = new DCategorias().Reporte();
            List<NCategorias> categoriasNegocio = new List<NCategorias>();

            foreach (DCategorias categoriaDatos in categoriasDatos)
            {
                NCategorias categoriaNegocio = new NCategorias();
                //categoriaNegocio.IDCategoria = categoriaDatos.IDCategoria;
                categoriaNegocio.Categoria = categoriaDatos.Categoria;
                categoriaNegocio.Notas = categoriaDatos.Notas;

                categoriasNegocio.Add(categoriaNegocio);
            }

            return categoriasNegocio;
        }
    }
```

```
//PRESENTATION
//================
//Form with ReportViewer and button BtnPrint

using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using CapaNegocio;

namespace CapaPresentacion.Formularios
{
    public partial class FormReportes : Form
    {
        public List<NCategorias> reporte = new List<NCategorias>();

        public FormReportes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void BtnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ReportViewer => AreaReporte
            AreaReporte.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

            List<NCategorias> categorias = NCategorias.ReporteCategorias();

            DataTable tablaCategorias = new DataTable("Categorias");
            tablaCategorias.Columns.Add("Categoria", typeof(string));
            tablaCategorias.Columns.Add("Notas", typeof(string));

            foreach (NCategorias categoria in categorias)
            {
                DataRow fila = tablaCategorias.NewRow();
                fila["Categoria"] = categoria.Categoria;
                fila["Notas"] = categoria.Notas;
                tablaCategorias.Rows.Add(fila);
            }

            AreaReporte.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            AreaReporte.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("CategoriasDS", tablaCategorias));
            AreaReporte.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ChronusFutsal.CapaPresentacion.Reportes.RepCategorias.rdlc";

            // Hacemos un refresh al reportViewer
            AreaReporte.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
```

I have the report named RepCategorias.rdlc with data source Object and Dataset named CategoriaDS from CapaNegocio.NCategorias with the fields Categoria and Notas.
I get error in the AreaReporte.RefreshReport()
System.NullReferenceException
Please could someone tell me the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error!. I just had to change the version of SqlServer.Type and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).